# Reading RTFs in Python - PyRTF

Tags: python, python-3.x, rtf

I need to read some .rtf files, so I’ve installed PyRTF. I looked online for some examples of PyRTF in practice and found the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append( '../' )

from PyRTF import *

SAMPLE_PARA = """The play opens one year after the death of Richard II, and
King Henry is making plans for a crusade to the Holy Land to cleanse himself
of the guilt he feels over the usurpation of Richard's crown. But the 
crusade must be postponed when Henry learns that Welsh rebels, led by Owen 
Glendower, have defeated and captured Mortimer. Although the brave Henry 
Percy, nicknamed Hotspur, has quashed much of the uprising, there is still 
much trouble in Scotland. King Henry has a deep admiration for Hotspur and 
he longs for his own son, Prince Hal, to display some of Hotspur's noble 
qualities. Hal is more comfortable in a tavern than on the battlefield, and 
he spends his days carousing with riff-raff in London. But King Henry also 
has his problems with the headstrong Hotspur, who refuses to turn over his 
prisoners to the state as he has been so ordered. Westmoreland tells King 
Henry that Hotspur has many of the traits of his uncle, Thomas Percy, the 
Earl of Worcester, and defying authority runs in the family."""

def MakeExample1() :
    doc     = Document()
    ss      = doc.StyleSheet
    section = Section()
    doc.Sections.append( section )

    #   text can be added directly to the section
    #   a paragraph object is create as needed
    section.append( 'Example 1' )

    #   blank paragraphs are just empty strings
    section.append( '' )

    #   a lot of useful documents can be created
    #   with little more than this
    section.append( 'A lot of useful documents can be created '
                'in this way, more advance formating is available '
                'but a lot of users just want to see their data come out '
                'in something other than a text file.' )
    return doc

def OpenFile( name ) :
    return file( '%s.rtf' % name, 'w' )

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    DR = Renderer()

    doc1 = MakeExample1()

    DR.Write( doc1, OpenFile( '1' ) )

    print('Finished')
```

However, when I try to run the code it doesn’t seem to recognise the imports:
'NameError: name 'Renderer' is not defined'

I checked the installation and it says I have the latest version (0.47.5) installed. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What about a minimal example? `from PyRTF import Renderer` works for me on python 2.7 and fails on 3.6 with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PropertySets'`. The `examples/examples.py` script works fine for me on Python 2.7. The library is not compatible with Python 3.